# How to sort data on the closest distance basis in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm preparing a map in QGIS 3.16.5 with the set of points and polygons in two layers. Unfortunately during a field work data were collected a bit randomly and objects of subsequent names are scattered on the map (by object I mean both: points & polygons). For instance, I have an object named 100 very close to object 1, while object 2 is located in a large distance. I want to rename objects to get some logical order of the names. I was going to export data to .csv, then change names in spreadsheet and import it again to a new layer.

Before that I need to sort data somehow using location and distance between objects as a rule. I would like to have object no. 1 in the first row, then, in the second row, the object that is closest to 1, in the third row object that is closest to this from the second row, in the fourth row object that is closest to this from the third row, and so on. In the end I would like to have numbers assigned respectively to each object.

Can it be done?

Comment: It depends what you define as a "row". Obviously if all northings are, say exactly 1050 then a row can be defined. However, if they are 1035, 1005, 1045, 1049... etc (as might be the case if collected with a hand-held GPS) is this a row? That might depend on the northings in the second row. If they are distinctly different from all in the first, as in 1205, 1198, 1211, 1200 then it can be done. I don't know field calculator well enough but in Excel you could create a new northing field with a formula like 10*ROUND(northing/10,-1). Same for easting then do a cascading sort on the new fields.

Comment: You probably want neighbouring label numbers to apply to neighbouring features. 

Your method will have problems when the closest item is one that has already been found. Then you will have large jumps between items, e.g, item 23 may be a long way from item 24, because it is the only remaining feature.

If you divide the area into cells in X,Y and use those as part of the index (like XXXYYY01), then you may get something more useful. There is also Morton ordering, which does something similar.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself clearly enough. By the row I meant a row in the resulting .csv file. I will try to explain myself once again. I'm looking for some tool that will work on a following basis.
1. I'm defining a starting object (point or polygon). This will be my first row in .csv.
2. The distances between the initial object (point or centroid if it is a polygon) and the every other object are calculated. The object with the shortest distance is marked as a second one. This will be my second row in .csv. The starting point (step 1) won't be considered in any farther calculations...

Comment: ...3. Now the algorithm is looking for the object with the shortest distance to the object that was founded in the previous step.  The object with the shortest distance is marked as the third one. This will be my third row in .csv. The 1st & 2nd object (step 1 and 2) won't be considered in calculations anymore.
The procedure is repeated till all objects will be ordered.